# Pgfplots: How do I make a style with consistent width while using `axis equal image=true`?

Tags: pgfplots

Workaround: If I set `height` very large, the width of the resulting plot is what I want and the resulting height is no more than it needs to be.  In my case, I can set `height=11in`, which is the height of my paper.

Edit: The width appears to begin shrinking when the height of the y-axis approaches the set width limit.  It's as if setting `width` actually sets a maximum of width or height.

I would like to set a standard style for pgfplots plots so that all plots have the same width.  I also want the x- and y-axis of any given plot to be at the same scale as each other, which I believe is accomplished with `axis equal image=true`.  Unfortunately, when I add `axis equal image=true` to the style, I no longer get consistent widths.  In fact, the width value seems to be largely ignored.

How can I get constant widths (height can vary) with `axis equal image=true`?  The following three plots all have different widths; I want them all to be 8cm wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.11,
  standard/.style={
    width=8cm,
    trig format plots=rad,
    axis equal image=true,
    axis lines=middle,
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[standard]
    \addplot[domain={0:pi}]{sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[standard,ymin=-2.0,ymax=1.0]
    \addplot[domain={0:pi}]{sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[standard]
    \addplot[domain={0:pi}]{2*sin(2*x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Playing around with it, it seems as if you just remove the `axis equal image=true` you get the desired results for the given graphs. It is easier to see if you also add `yticklabel style={text width=3em,align=right}`.  Perhaps `axis equal=true` might be needed but it does not seem to be needed in the given MWE.

Comment: That is my entire question.  How to make `width` have affect  while maintaining the same scale on the x- and y-axes.  (I prefer `axis equal image` over `axis equal`, otherwise some plots would have wasted height.)

Comment: If you really don't have an upper limit for the height of your plots, you can set `height=50cm` (or some other large value). That way, only the `width` value will limit the dimensions of the plots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments and OP added that at the top of his question.